# How can I download this site with WebClient of .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, web-scraping, webclient

I cannot download this site: https://verify.sos.ga.gov/verification/Search.aspx by using WebClient of .NET; during download process, I get Forbidden error. My code is like this: I first go to the HomePage; after that, I go to the link page, and from there I go to Search page. I can download html for HomePage and Link page; however, when I try to download the Search page, I get Forbidden error.

My code is written in C# .NET and I am using version 4.8.1. Below is my code excerpt. Will someone please help?

```
UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/121.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/121.0.0.0";
CookieAwareWebClient3 client = new CookieAwareWebClient3();
client.Headers.Add("Host", "sos.ga.gov");
client.Headers.Add("Sec-Fetch-Dest", "document");
client.Headers.Add("Sec-Fetch-Mode", "navigate");
client.Headers.Add("Sec-Fetch-Site", "none");
client.Headers.Add("Sec-Fetch-User", "?1");
client.Headers.Add("TE", "trailers");
client.Headers.Add("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", "1");
client.Headers.Add("user-agent", UserAgent);
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
url = "https://sos.ga.gov/";
try
{
    byte[] beginResults = client.DownloadData(url);    
    beginOutput = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(beginResults);
}
catch(WebException ex)
{
    error = ex.Message;
}
client.TransferCookies();

client.Headers.Add("Host", "sos.ga.gov");
client.Headers.Add("Referer", "https://sos.ga.gov/");
client.Headers.Add("Sec-Fetch-Dest", "document");
client.Headers.Add("Sec-Fetch-Mode", "navigate");
client.Headers.Add("Sec-Fetch-Site", "same-origin");
client.Headers.Add("Sec-Fetch-User", "?1");
client.Headers.Add("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", "1");
client.Headers.Add("user-agent", UserAgent);

url = "https://sos.ga.gov/licensing-division-license-lookup";
try
{
    byte[] beginResults1 = client.DownloadData(url);     
    beginOutput1 = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(beginResults1);
}
catch (WebException ex)
{
    error = ex.Message;
}
client.TransferCookies();
client.Headers.Add("Host", "verify.sos.ga.gov");
client.Headers.Add("Referer", "https://sos.ga.gov/");
client.Headers.Add("Sec-Fetch-Dest", "document");
client.Headers.Add("Sec-Fetch-Mode", "navigate");
client.Headers.Add("Sec-Fetch-Site", "same-site");
client.Headers.Add("Sec-Fetch-User", "?1");
client.Headers.Add("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", "1");
client.Headers.Add("user-agent", UserAgent);

url = "https://verify.sos.ga.gov/verification/Search.aspx";
try
{
    byte[] beginResults2 = client.DownloadData(url);    // I get Forbidden error here
    beginOutput2 = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(beginResults2);
}
catch (WebException ex)
{
    error = ex.Message;
}
```

```
public class CookieAwareWebClient3 : WebClient
{
    public CookieAwareWebClient3()
    {
        CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        ResponseCookies = new CookieCollection();
    }

    public CookieContainer CookieContainer { get; set; }
    public CookieCollection ResponseCookies { get; set; }

    public void TransferCookies()
    {
        CookieContainer.Add(ResponseCookies);
    }
    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)base.GetWebRequest(address);
        request.KeepAlive = true;
        request.CookieContainer = CookieContainer;
        return request;

    }
    protected override WebResponse GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
    {
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
        var response = (HttpWebResponse)base.GetWebResponse(request);


        this.ResponseCookies = response.Cookies;
        return response;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I get error at byte[] beginResults2 = client.DownloadData(url);    line. It is not working. What I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I will try to provide an answer even though I'm not entirely sure about the problem because I can't find the website you mentioned. Some of my answer is based on my opinion, and you don't have to follow it. My guess is that your problem is relatively easy to solve.

Firstly, in my opinion, there are quite a few duplications in your code. You seem to be copying too much code. Secondly, since you're building code as application, why are you using such an old version of .NET? Nowadays, you have the option to use .NET 8 or .NET 6 if you don't want to go for a higher version. I don't understand why you're using .NET 4.8.1. The Webclient class has been deprecated for a long time. I would recommend using HttpClient to replace it and rewrite your code.

In the following answer, I will provide a solution based on .NET 6 and HttpClient. First, I will provide a solution using just HttpClient, and then I will use a library that could help you with web scraping basics.

Now, let's discuss your problem. I believe you are using the wrong URL. I can't open the website in a browser, so why would C# be able to access it? Even when I use the library-based code, it downloads an empty HTML without throwing any errors, just like my browser. Additionally, the header I see in my browser suggests that the site might be protected by Cloudflare. If my assumption is correct, you won't be able to access it with C# because currently, you can't bypass Cloudflare with it.

However, if my guess is correct, you should use a URL like this: 'https://sos.ga.gov/search?division=Licensing&board=&type=&query=[YOUR QUERY HERE]' or 'https://sos.ga.gov/search?division=&board=&type=&query=[YOUR QUERY HERE]'.

I think this should solve your problem, but I'm not certain if my guess is correct. If you don't want to update your .NET version, you can still try with the URL provided.

```cs
HttpClient httpClient = new(); // Create an instance of HttpClient for making HTTP requests

async Task TestSiteDownload()
{
    // Use HttpClient to download the HTML content of the specified websites
    string firstHTML = await httpClient.GetStringAsync("https://sos.ga.gov/");
    string secondHTML = await httpClient.GetStringAsync("https://sos.ga.gov/licensing-division-license-lookup");
    // I believe this is the site you are looking for. Apologies if it's not accurate. Searched: "NO"
    string thirdHTML = await httpClient.GetStringAsync("https://sos.ga.gov/search?division=&board=&type=&query=no");
}
```

Here, I am using the library called 'Shard.DownloadAssistant' for .NET 6. It allows you to scan a website and search for references to other sites. It does not explicitly print the results, but the results should be contained within it. You can find it on [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/).

```cs
async Task TestSiteDownloadWithLibrary()
{
    // Start downloading the websites
    SiteRequest homePage = new("https://sos.ga.gov/");
    SiteRequest license = new("https://sos.ga.gov/licensing-division-license-lookup");
    SiteRequest searchSite = new("https://sos.ga.gov/search?division=&board=&type=&query=no");

    // Wait for the downloading to finish
    await searchSite.Task;

    // Get the HTML content of a website
    Console.WriteLine(searchSite.HTML);

    // Print all the links found on the website along with their descriptions (if any). Not sure if this will be helpful.
    foreach (WebItem link in searchSite.Links)
        Console.WriteLine($"{link.Description} - Url: {link.URL}");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am trying to open this url: https://verify.sos.ga.gov/verification/Search.aspx. This url has a form, which I want to populate programmatically and do a post request to verify a license. Shard.DownloadAssistant works for other urls but Shard.DownloadAssistant does not work for https://verify.sos.ga.gov/verification/Search.aspx. Do you know why I cannot open https://verify.sos.ga.gov/verification/Search.aspx url with the sample you provided ( Shard.DownloadAssistant)? Please let me know your thought. Thank you.

Answer (score -2):

```
public class CookieAwareWebClient3 : WebClient
{
    public CookieAwareWebClient3()
    {
        CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        ResponseCookies = new CookieCollection();
    }

    public CookieContainer CookieContainer { get; set; }
    public CookieCollection ResponseCookies { get; set; }

    public void TransferCookies()
    {
        CookieContainer.Add(ResponseCookies);
    }
    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)base.GetWebRequest(address);
        request.KeepAlive = true;
        request.CookieContainer = CookieContainer;
        return request;

    }
    protected override WebResponse GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
    {
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
        var response = (HttpWebResponse)base.GetWebResponse(request);


        this.ResponseCookies = response.Cookies;
        return response;
    }
}
```

all are woriking properly try it once

Comment: please always explain what you are doing by adding comments to the code and more explanation in the text

Comment: I am doing web scrapping ( downloading html of a site). I have placed comment on my code. I get Forbidden error at this line: https://verify.sos.ga.gov/verification/Search.aspx